# When Google Maps API calls "mapsbackend.loadMap" method as reported in API console?

Tags: google-maps, google-api

someone could explain to me WHEN GMap Javascript API calls the `mapsbackend.loadMap` method as reported in Google API console?

Is it called when the first script is get from Google using "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=..." url?
Is it called when all the GMap objects are dynamically loaded from Google server?
Or is it called when the map is finally rendered on the screen? (in this case, the method is never called if the map container tag is `display: hidden` or `display: none`?)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you create a `google.maps.Map`-instance a map-load will be counted.

From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage#usage_limits):

> *A map load is counted when a map is initialized on a web page*

I've  tested it a little bit, it seems that a map-load will be counted the first time when the tilesloaded-event of a map fires.

- This event  will fire even when the map is hidden, also when the map-div isn't a part of the document at all.
- It will not fire when one of the required arguments for the constructor is missing(e.g. zoom), but as soon as you set the required property the tilesloaded-event will fire and the load will be counted.